# Adding spinner element into react throws dependency error

Tags: reactjs, npm, spin.js

I added a spinner to my react app

```
npm install react-spinjs --save
```

After installation I get the following warning

```
npm WARN react-spinjs@3.0.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.1 but none was installed.
```

It looks like the _react object in the spinner code is undefined

```
69 |   config: _react.PropTypes.object
```

I have "react": "16.0.0" installed.  Do I have to go down to 15.0.1 to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

That only means the dependencies on `react-spinjs` aren't updated and is asking for an older version of react. Version 16 was just released, so it's only normal it will take time before every dep is updated.

React 16 didn't really introduced breaking changes though, so you can ignore that warning.

Comment: The problem I am running into is react in the spinner element is undefined.

Comment: I found another one built on react 16.  Solved the problem.